# Machine learning - determining a probabilistic price

Tags: machine-learning

I have large amounts of data concerning transactions about objects. Objects are defined with categories of keywords. Transactions are defined by categories of keywords too (but not the same). For each particular object, I have tons of raws for each combination of transaction conditions.

Let’s say that **for a particular object**, the **price of the transaction** is a function of the conditions in which this transaction occurred.

For instance, the buyer will be able to sell this object for $30 if the weather is sunny at the moment of the transaction, and for $40 if it’s raining.

Things get more complicated because I don't want the pricing function for each particular object. Instead, I want the computer to learn a way of defining a probabilistic price based upon a set of characteristics of objects, *and* a set of conditions of transaction.

Put in another way, I want the computer to learn `f` in

```
expected_price = f(characteristics_of_object, conditions_of_transactions).
```

**Example**

Let’s say **objects** can be tagged within those categories:

```
colors: black, blue, red, green, white
materials: wood, steel, plastic, glass
shapes: circle, square, triangle, oval
```

So that any object can combine multiple tags from each category in such a way:

```
my_foo_object = {
    “color”: [“black”, “blue”],
    “material”: [“wood”],
    “shape”: [“round”, “square”]
}
```

As I said, **transactions** are defined by their conditions, like:

```
weather: sunny, cloudy, rain
payment: credit_card, cash, check
age_of_buyer: 21, 22, 23, 24……., 55, 56
age_of_seller: 21, 22, 23, 24……., 55, 56
country_code: us, uk, fr, de, jp, nl
```

A particular transaction being defined by something like:

```
my_foo_transaction = {
    “object”: my_foo_object,
    “weather”: [“cloudy”, “rain”],
    “payment”: “credit_card”,
    “age_of_buyer”: 29,
    “age_of_seller”: 43,
    “country_code”: “us”,
    “price”: 84
}
```

What I want in the end is to be able to tell a reasonable expected price for, as an example:

```
object_color: red
object_shape: round
weather: sunny
age_of_buyer: 52
(without necessarily having to specify all the variables)
=> price?
```

Along with an estimation of the interval of confidence (so that if this interval is big for a particular query, I can tell there is no discernable pattern for the conditions/characteristics specified).

I know it doesn’t sound like trivial stuff and I’m obviously not asking for a full solution (this would be ridiculous).

Did any of you ever have to go through a similar problem? Do you have any ideas, leads or advice on things to take into consideration? What would be the best paradigm(s) to apply to treat this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get an interval of confidence, but this sounds like it would fit instance based learning methods. Your features would be the characteristics of objects and the features of the transactions. Then, once presented with a query, find the closest existing points to your query and take their average, or take an average of all the points weighted by distance. This might not work very fast with a lot of data however.

Comment: @IVlad helpful, thanks - concerning the interval of confidence, perhaps it could be done by calculating not only an average but also a standard deviation of closest existing points?

Comment: Yes, that might work. The more important issue would be time. There are other algorithm that would be faster, but I'm even less sure about intervals of confidence for those...